# Tense agreement after "if it means that"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, conditionals

I've read that in conditional sentences, tenses don't have to match. Is this true for sentences that contain "if it means"? In the examples below, I'm trying to say something like "I won't write to you if it's going to help me not miss you".

> - I will not write you if it means that I won't miss you.
> - I will not write you if it means that I don't have to miss you.
> - I will not write you if it'll mean that I won't miss you.

Do these basically mean the same thing or is one more right than the other?

Comment: I think "I won't write you if it means that I won't need to miss you" sounds best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the semantics of OP's example a bit odd, so I'll switch to...

> 1: *We won't go to the party if it means **we need** a babysitter*
>    2: *We won't go to the party if it means **we will need** a babysitter*
>    3: *We won't go to the party if it means **we would need** a babysitter*

Those alternatives (given in descending order of popularity) are all valid, and all mean the same.

If you're doubtful about #3, consider [*"...if it means I would have to [do something]"*](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if%20it%20means%20we%20would%20need%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22if%20it%20means%20I%20would%20have%20to%22&oq=%22if%20it%20means%20I%20would%20have%20to%22&gs_l=serp.3...24066.24728.2.25773.3.3.0.0.0.0.42.117.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.74TuIRGcGss&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892). But also note that in such "hypothetical" constructions, *"I **wouldn't** do this [if it **meant** I would have to do that"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if%20it%20means%20we%20would%20need%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22if%20it%20meant%20I%20would%20have%20to%22&oq=%22if%20it%20meant%20I%20would%20have%20to%22&gs_l=serp.3...128681.129109.5.129908.2.2.0.0.0.0.87.152.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab._dxvVy0z_gU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892)* is far more common.

---

OP's third example (changing present tense *means* to future tense *will mean*) is non-standard.

Comment: Wow, thank you! So as a practice sentence, is the following sentence okay? I tried to mimic your examples by using would instead of will. "I would quit my current job if it means I will earn more money."

Comment: @Pato: As my last paragraph indicates, if you introduce your hypothetical scenario with *"I **would** [do something] if..."*, the far more common (and more grammatically correct/consistent) way to continue is with *"...if it **meant** [something else] **would** happen"*. So in the example you've just presented there, the "standard" form is *"I **would** quit my current job if it **meant** I **would** earn more money."* Alternatively (perhaps less common, but equally correct) you could say *"I **will** quit my current job if it **means** I **will** earn more money."*

Comment: ...It's also perfectly reasonable to discard the final "future tense" indicator, so you could say *"I **will** quit my current job if it **means** I earn more money."*